# How to add MimeType to a serialized file output in order to categorize It as specific file format

Tags: android, file, mime-types, java-io, android-file

I serialize some objects in order to save them on a file.
This file should be deserialized to get the object content in It back. 
Obviously a file created in this way doesn't have any specific MimeType that can identify It.

I want to define a my own MimeType and add this to the file, in order to create my own File Types.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Objects are typically serialized in binary format. So there is no way to distinguish files based on their format. I suggest using different file extensions based on the object types they hold. If you don't like this approach you can also invent your metadata database for your serialized files.

Comment: I know that they cannot be identified and for this reason My question asks how to add a custom MimeType in order to make this possible. there are several reason that makes using just a file extension a not good solution